# C++ Builder XE can't successfully convert project from BCB6

Tags: migration, c++builder, projects-and-solutions, c++builder-6, c++builder-xe

I am trying to convert old BCB6 project to C++ Builder XE project. Version of development environment is following:

*Embarcadero C++ Builder XE Version 15.0.3953.35171*

First step was to create blank new project (File -> New -> VCL Forms Application - C++ Builder). After that I added to project all files and all forms from old project and deleted blank form that was auto-created. Second step was to convert *AnsiString* objects to *UnicodeString* objects where it was necessary. Then I tried to build the project. Compilation phase ran without the errors. But I am now stuck with linker errors (in BCB6 all was OK):

```
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external 'Chart::TChart::' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\LNG.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxisTitle::SetCaption(const System::UnicodeString)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TCustomAxisPanel::GetSeries(int)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartSeries::SetVertAxis(const Teengine::TVertAxis)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teeprocs::TCustomTeePanelExtended::SetAllowZoom(bool)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxis::SetMaximum(const const double)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxis::SetMinimum(const const double)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxis::SetLogarithmic(bool)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxis::SetAutomatic(bool)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2341,5): error : Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Teengine::TChartAxis::SetDesiredIncrement(const const double)' referenced from C:\TEMP\WSCS\DEBUG\WIN32\F_LOADPOINT_DETAILS.OBJ
```

How can I resolve these errors? Is something that I am doing erroneously? TChart is standard component both in BCB6 and in C++ Builder XE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened all forms in my project. Right-clicked on them and checked menu item "Text DFM". Now build completes successfully. Its really magic I can't comprehend it.